# Efficient way to rename files

Tags: windows-10, rename

### Problem

I have two folders: `folder1` and `folder2`.

- `folder1` has 39 files with filename of the form `Screenshot (n).png`, where 1 ≤ *n* ≤ 74, not in order.

```
D:\folder1

Screenshot (1).png
Screenshot (2).png
Screenshot (5).png
Screenshot (8).png
.
.     (no pattern)
.
Screenshot (74).png
```

- `folder2` has 145 files with filenames of the form `Screenshot (k).png` for all *k* such that 1 ≤ *k* ≤ 145.

```
D:\folder2

Screenshot (1).png
Screenshot (2).png
Screenshot (3).png
Screenshot (4).png
.
.
.
Screenshot (145).png
```

- Some files are common, but have different filenames.
- I want to *copy* the files in `folder1` and `folder2` to a new folder, `folder0`, and have the filenames of the form `Screenshot (m).png` for all *m* such that 1 ≤ *m* ≤ 184, where m is assigned depending on the `Date Created` attribute (Windows 10), and also don't want to have any duplicate files.

```
D:\folder0

Screenshot (1).png
Screenshot (2).png
Screenshot (3).png
.
.
.
Screenshot (184).png
```

---

### Possible solution

- Rename the files in `folder1` to `Screenshot (a).png` for all *a* such that 1 ≤ *a* ≤ 39, where *a* is assigned depending on the `Date Created` attribute.
- Rename the files in `folder2` to `Screenshot (b).png` for all *b* such that 101 ≤ *b* ≤ 245, where *b* is assigned depending on the `Date Created` attribute.
- *Copy* the files of `folder1` and `folder2` to `inefficientSolution` folder.
- Get rid of duplicate files, where two (or more) files are termed duplicate if they have the same `Date Created` and `Size` attributes.
- Rename the files in `inefficientSolution` folder to `Screenshot (c).png` for all *c* such that 1 ≤ *c* ≤ 184, where *c* is assigned depending on the `Date Created` attribute.
- *Move* the files in `inefficientSolution` folder to `folder0`.

---

### What I tried

- `PowerRename` (PowerToys) for renaming. It has an `Enumerate Items` option, but it doesn't allow me to change the initial index (i.e., starting enumeration from, say, 10, instead of 1).
- `Bulk Rename Utility`, but I guess that it enumerates the files depending on the `Date Modified` attribute, not the `Date Created` attribute.

---

### Help

I don't have the required tools and knowledge. How should I tackle this?

---

## Thanks!

Comment: @Robert Thank you very much, it worked as intended. Please post this as an answer so that I can accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mass renaming is a feature of Windows Explorer so except for duplicate files removal you can do all what you want using Windows Explorer:

1. Select all files in `folder1` and rename them in Windows Explorer to `a`
2. Select all files in `folder2` and rename them in Windows Explorer to `b`
3. Move all files from `folder1` and all files from `folder2` to the `folderFinal`.
4. Enable the column you want to sort the files and sort the files as you want
5. Select all files and rename them

Now you have all files from both folders renamed according to the current sort order.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a powershell script:

```
function RenAs([string[]]$path,[int[]]$iV){
  $iVi = 0
  Foreach ($P in $Path){
    $i = $iV[0]
    Get-ChildItem "$P" | 
      Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | 
        Sort-Object CreationTime | 
          Foreach {
            $i += 1
            Rename-Item -Path "$_" -Newname "Screenshot `($($i)`)$($_.Extension)"
          }
  $iVi += 1
  }
}
RenAs "D:\folder1","D:\folder2" 1,100
Copy-Item -path "D:\folder1\*","D:\folder2\*" -destination "D:\inefficientSolution\"
RenAs "D:\inefficientSolution" 1
Move-Item -path "D:\inefficientSolution\*" -Destination "D:\folder0\"
```

Replace "D:\ineffiecientSolution" with folder path.